In C++ gRPC is there a way to call a gRPC method from within another gRPC method?
As an example if there was a proto file like this:
syntax = "proto3";
package mypackage;
option java_package = "com.example";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service MyService {
  rpc Foo(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
}

service OtherService {
  rpc Bar(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
}

So lets say these two services are implemented in the same binary and when a client calls MyService.Foo internally inside my implementation of MyService.Foo I want to call OtherService.Bar to do something, is that possible? If so, how?

gRPC is a remote procedure call (RPC) mechanism i.e. a client invokes methods|functions that are implemented usually on a remote server via a network.
The gRPC functionality includes the (un)marshaling between client and server (usually via protocol buffers) and transmission over the network.
All that's being invoked is some method|function (just usually on a different machine) and so, just as you would invoke any other method|function, you can invoke one gRPC method from another though you'd generally do this without going through the second gRPC's public signature and use some local function invocation.
Corollary: you only need use gRPC calls to invoke methods when the method is remote; if it's local (on a client or server), invoke it as any other function.
There's a wrinkle that the second gRPC method could be on a third machine in which case there's a second RPC between server1 and server2 in which case server1 creates a gRPC client against server2 and makes the 2nd gRPC method call.
Scenario #1: client invokes method on server1 which invokes another method on server1
pseudocode
Server implements both services
namespace MyService {
  function grpcFoo(params) {
    // Convert Proto to local type
    invoke local.doesFoo(params)
    // Convert local type to Proto
    return
  }
}
namespace OtherService {
  function grpcBar(params) {
    // Convert Proto to local type
    invoke local.doesBar(params)
    // Convert local type to Proto
    return
  }
}
namespace local {
  function doesFoo(params) {
    invoke doesBar(params)
    return
  }
  function doesBar(params) {
    // Does something
    return
  }
}

Scenario #2: client invokes method on server1 which creates a second client and invokes method on server2
pseudocode
Server1 implements MyService
namespace MyService {
  function grpcFoo(params) {
    // Create gRPC client against Server #2
    invoke otherservice.grpcBar(params)
    return
  }
}

Server2 implements OtherService
namespace OtherService {
  function grpcBar(params) {
    // Does something
    return
  }
}


Ok I understand both scenarios and scenario #2 I am familiar with and understand how that can work. In scenario #1 effectively you are saying that a grpc method cannot call another grpc method directly, instead use normal C++ methods/objects to allow Foo to call Bar. Where all this is coming from is as I looked through the grpc API  I did not see a way to create a Channel from inside a grpc method so that I can use it to create a stub for another service that is implemented by the same process.

You probably (!) can call one gRPC method from another. I'm unfamiliar with the C++ implementation and so can't comment on it. I think you likely shouldn't want to do this. Partly because of the issue your cite but also the possible need to (un)marshal types into proto messages to do so. The gRPC methods could be idealized as a facade that exposes local methods to remote clients and, in this case, it would seem to always be preferable to just call those local methods directly.
